# How to feed autocomplete data to a fish alias?

Tags: fish

I am starting with `fish` and one of the things I could not find in the extensive documentation was autocomplete feeds.

There is mention of [Tab Completions](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_tab_completions) in the tutorial but it addresses existing the existence of the mechanism itself, not its configuration.

I have a bunch of virtual machines I connect to via

```
machinectl shell <name of machine> /bin/bash
```

I could make alises for all my machines via

```
function cm
    machinectl $argv shell /bin/bash; 
end
```

but this requires to remember and type the machine name.

How could I use the output of `machinectl list | tail -n +2 | head -n -2 | cut -f1 -d' '` as a feed/hint to my `cm` command so that it shows them when using <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

---

EDIT: I somehow missed this right at the top of the documentation: [Tab completion](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#completion) (I found it after reviewing the answers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you off to a good start:

```
complete --command cm --no-files \
--arguments '(machinectl list | tail -n +2 | head -n -2 | cut -f1 -d" ")'
```

Entering that at the command line will activate it for the current session; to make it permanent add the line to a completions file as Kurtis describes (`~/.config/fish/completions/cm.fish`).

Answer (score 3):

See `help complete`. You'll find the completions that ship with fish, including completions for ssh, in `$__fish_datadir/completions`. A completion you write for a private function or command would be placed in `~/.config/fish/completions/$cmd_name.fish`